# Icon size of a firefox addon / extensions in pixels

Tags: plugins, firefox-addon

What is the correct dimensions (width and height) for a Firefox plugin or addon icon in pixels ?

Is it the same size dimensions for chrome extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32x32 in Firefox 3.6 or lower. Since Firefox 4.0 it can be up to 48x48 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/install_manifests#iconURL).

Comment: In addition to what Matthew said: starting with Firefox 4 you should also include a large 64x64 icon (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/install_manifests#icon64URL). If present, this one will be displayed on the add-on details page in the add-on manager instead of the small icon.

Comment: 48x48 and another icon 64x64 , check https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/dev-guide/package-spec.html for addons SDK